# Newline not working on string share to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, sharing

I have an object MyObject that contains two strings

```
public class MyObject{ 

    String title
    String description
}
```

I want to share this object on the following platform (SMS, EMail, Facebook)

so my code is

```
public String getMySharingStringViaSMS(){

    return title + "\r\n" + description
}

public String getMySharingStringViaEMAIL(){

    return title + "<br />" + description
}
```

The problem now that both (\r\n) and (br) didn't work on Facebook

so can any one help, How Can I make only one method that handle them all

Comment: @AmirElsayadIsmail ..Did u get the solution of these problem, plz let me know... I have aslo stcked in the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Share some stuff on Facebook require implementing FacebookSdk 3.0, follow this tutorial :
http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html

The main goal is to provide "Login" via facebook to share something on wall.
Once login works, try this method :

```
private void publishStory(String hash, String title, String user) {

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (session != null){
    // Check for publish permissions    
    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                .NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
    }
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("name", title);
    postParams.putString("caption", "By Recommend Android");
    postParams.putString("description", user+" "+"STRONGLY recommends"+" "+title);
    postParams.putString("link", "http://re.co/"+hash);
    postParams.putString("picture", "http://re.co/assets/img/useful-exp.png");

    Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            JSONObject graphResponse = response
                    .getGraphObject()
                    .getInnerJSONObject();
            String postId = null;
            try {
                postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
            }
```

Don't forget that your Html tags must be declare in your strings.xml, like this way:

```
<string name="demoStr"><Data><![CDATA[ <b>ABC</b><br /> something ]]> </Data></string>
```

Then getString() will be get `"<b>ABC</b><br />something"`